# Hot to skip hidden rows while parsing an excel file with xlsx-populate

Tags: node.js, xlsx-populate

I'm reading one sheet with the range and I want to skip hidden rows. Is there a way to do this?
This code reading all rows:

```
const values = workbook.sheet("Sheet20").range("D15:G577").value();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with exceljs (https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs)

```
require('core-js/modules/es.promise');
require('core-js/modules/es.string.includes');
require('core-js/modules/es.object.assign');
require('core-js/modules/es.object.keys');
require('core-js/modules/es.symbol');
require('core-js/modules/es.symbol.async-iterator');
require('regenerator-runtime/runtime');
const ExcelJS = require('exceljs/dist/es5');
```

...

```
let filename = path.resolve(__dirname + "../../", "file1323.xlsx");
var workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
workbook.xlsx.readFile(filename)
  .then(function () {            
    const worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet('Sheet20');
    for (let i = 15; i < 1000; i++) { // start from row 15, get 1000 rows
      if (!worksheet.getRow(i).hidden) {
        let row = worksheet.getRow(i);
        console.log(row.getCell('D').value + " " + row.getCell('G').value);                    
      }
    }            
});
```